# uninitialized constant Users (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github, devise

I want my application to run on Heroku. When i try to open my app throws an error. heroku logs

/app/app/controllers/Users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant Users (NameError)

I must change my controllers/Users/ folder name to users on github. 
How can i change the folder name on github ?

If anyone can explain it step by step. Thank you

Answer : https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location/

Comment: Could you can explain step by step what you doing?

Comment: I fixed it ref. https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location/